# How to pass through gestures to an object underneath?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to hit an object behind the top most visible object. I was trying to achieve this by using the `GestureDetector`'s `behavior` property.
The code for this is as follows:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => print("Bottom"),
      child: new Container(
        color: Colors.redAccent,
        child: new Center(
          child: new GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => print("Top"),
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
            child: new Container(
              width: 200.0,
              height: 200.0,
              color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.3),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. Only ***Top*** gets printed to the console. The docs make it seem like this is the correct way of doing it, but perhaps I'm missing something here?

Comment: your code is working fine for me, its printing both top and bottom in the console

Comment: @ShyjuM What version of Flutter are you using?

Comment: the latest one.

Comment: @ShyjuM Could you check again? Because I've asked around and it doesn't seem to work for others either.

Comment: Do you mean you want to print "Bottom" (only) when tapping on the Center widget?

Comment: "Bottom" or both. It doesn't really matter for my implementation.

Comment: @BramVanbilsen I presume you also want to handle it in the top widget? Because just removing the onTap from the top one causes it to pass through to the lower one. If you need to handle it and pass it back, I found a bug of methods on BuildContext like `ancestorWidgetOfExactType` however I can't seem to get them to return anything but null :-(

Comment: @DannyTuppeny I want the bottom one or both to receive the `onTap` event tbh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the bottom one or both to receive the `onTap` event tbh.

If just getting the `Bottom` event is fine, then simply removing:

```
onTap: () => print("Top"),
```

Works for me. After commenting out that line, it prints `Bottom` when I tap on the inner square.

Tested with this version:

```
Dannys-MacBook:flutter danny$ flutter --version
Flutter 0.4.5-pre.96 • channel master • https://github.com/DanTup/flutter.git
Framework • revision d79f2ee223 (12 hours ago) • 2018-05-26 12:29:53 -0700
Engine • revision 1ed25ca7b7
Tools • Dart 2.0.0-dev.58.0.flutter-f981f09760
```

That said, removing the inner `GestureDetector` does the same to, so I'm wondering if there's some reason you added it?

Comment: Removing the callback means nothing is happening. According to the question it should be possible to have both of them firing. I don't think this answer is correct.

Comment: The question doesn't seem to be specific about whether both are required, it only mentions bottom. This answer starts with "If just getting the Bottom event is fine" and was accepted by the OP, so I presume that's what they wanted.

Comment: To be honest, yes, depends on how you read the question, or what answer are you looking for.

Answer (score 2):

For those who need to be able to have both detectors firing (so that they print both 'Top' AND 'Bottom'), you can try `Listener` with `opaque` behaviour as the top detector instead of the usual `GestureDetector`:

```
return Listener(
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
  onPointerUp: (PointerUpEvent event) {
    print('Bottom');
  },
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      print('Top');
    },
    child: Center(
      child: Container(
        height: 100.w,
        width: 100.w,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

EDIT: Actually, it seems like you can even omit setting Listener's `behavior`, as `translucent`, `opaque` and `deferToChild` all work.